# Persist file upload through failed form validation

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to persist a file uploaded on a file upload input when my form fails to validate.  I do not want to use HTML5 validation, because I want to display my own messages.  This means that the request has to go to the server and the page has to be reloaded...resulting in the user being required to upload the file again.

Comment: Your going to get down voted fast. Show some examples of your script and form and define more clearly what needs to happen and what you have tried to solve it

Comment: I haven't tried anything actually. My question was to get me on the right track with what to try. I actually came up with a method using a hidden field to achieve it but I am thinking that sprise' option of using the session might be a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to save the file in the validation process and tie it to the user with a session.